# Pegar ID em sequencia baseado no último inserido

Tags: php, pdo

Estou com um problema que está me dando problemas.

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
$sql = $pdo->prepare ("SELECT cpf,idUser FROM `tblContacts` where cpf = '".$cpf."' limit 1");
$sql->execute();
$row = $sql->fetch();

if($row != null)
  {
    //  echo "SQL 01 ". $sql;
    $randomicId = $row->idUser;
  } 
  else
  {
    switch ($horaAtual) {
      case ($horaAtual > $hora1 && $horaAtual < $hora2): $periodo = 'manha'; break;
      case ($horaAtual > $hora2 && $horaAtual < $hora3): $periodo = 'tarde'; break;
      default: $periodo =  'manha';
    }

    $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM `tblUser` where grupo = 'vendas' and ativo = 1 and periodo = '".$periodo."' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
    $stmt = $pdo->query($sql2); 
    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if($row['idUser'] != null)
    {
      //echo "SQL 02 ". $sql2;
      $randomicId = $row['idUser'];
    }
  }
```

O código tem 2 partes:

Quando um cliente faz um cadastro, eu pego o ID de um usuário e atribuo a este cadastro:

```
id   nome_cliente  ......  idUsuario

1    fulano                   2
```

Se o cliente fulano fizer um outro cadastro futuramente, o sistema verifica se tem algum cadastro igual no banco, se tiver, ele usuário o mesmo ID do usuário.

Se não tem nenhum cadastro no banco, o sistema passar por um processo de verificar para pegar o ID de algum usuário:

O sistema pega a hora atual:

- se for antes das 15h, ele fará um consulta no banco e selecionará os usuários do período da manhã.
- se for depois das 15h, ele fará um consulta no banco e selecionará os usuários do período da tarde.

Tabela usuários:

```
id   nome      periodo  ...
1    siclano    tarde
```

O sistema, após verificar o período, pega um ID aleatório com o `RAND() limit 1` .

Assim, o código está funcionando.

Mas, pegando o ID aleatório, está acontecendo o seguinte problema: está ainda mais cadastros para 1 usuário do que para outro.

Então, eu queria, invés de pegar aleatório, atribuir um ID em sequencia.

Verifica o horário, a insere o ID em sequencia (obs: Os ID variam).

```
IdUsuario : 2,34,45 

cadastro 1  - idUsuario : 2
cadastro 2  - idUsuario : 34
cadastro 3  - idUsuario : 45
cadastro 4  - idUsuario : 2
....
```

Alguém pode ajudar a fazer dessa forma?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pra fazer esse controle você precisa ter um campo onde controle qual foi o último usuário utilizado. Sugiro fazer uma normalização no teu banco, alterando o campo `periodo` passando os dados pra uma tabela e armazenando apenas o ID desses registros na tabela de usuários, e armazene nessa tabela qual foi o último usuário utilizado, assim terás uma fila para cada turno. Segue um exemplo.

#### Modelagem básica:

**Turnos**

```
CREATE TABLE `turnos`(
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  nome VARCHAR(45),
  lastfunc INT
);

INSERT INTO turnos (nome) VALUES ('manhã'), ('tarde');

 _________________________
| id | nome  | lastfunc   |
|____|_______|____________|
| 1  | manhã |            |
|____|_______|____________|
| 2  | tarde |            |
|____|_______|____________|
2 registros
```

A coluna `lastfunc` será usada para controlar a sequência de usuários/funcionarios.

**Funcionários**

```
CREATE TABLE `funcionarios`(
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  nome VARCHAR(45),
  turno_id INT NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (turno_id) REFERENCES turnos(id)
);

INSERT INTO funcionarios (nome, turno_id)  VALUES
('João', 1), ('Maria', 1), ('José', 2), ('Joana', 2);

 __________________________
| id | nome     | turno_id |
|____|__________|__________|
| 1  | João     | 1        |  ---
|____|__________|__________|    |-- Turno da Manhã
| 2  | Maria    | 1        |  ---
|____|__________|__________|
| 3  | José     | 2        |  ---
|____|__________|__________|    |-- Turno da Tarde
| 4  | Joana    | 2        |  ---
|____|__________|__________|
4 registros
```

**Clientes**

```
CREATE TABLE `clientes`(
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  nome VARCHAR(45),
  funcionario_id INT,
  FOREIGN KEY (funcionario_id) REFERENCES funcionarios(id)
);

 ____________________________
| id | nome | funcionario_id |
|____|______|________________|
0 registro
```

#### Código e Lógica.

A lógica consiste em que cada vez que cadastrarmos um cliente, buscamos um funcionário para associa-lo ao seu cadastro, a regra de
busca do funcionário é a seguinte:

- Se cliente cadastrado busca existente no cadastro
- Senão Se existe próximo da fila busca com base no horário
- Se não existe próximo, busca o primeiro da fila

Com base nessa regra, construi o seguinte código: (Detalhamento nos comentários)

```
// Altere CPF e Variável $turno para testes
$novoCliente = Array(
   'cpf' => '66666666668',
   'nome' => 'Fulano Pereira Pinto',
   'funcionario_id' => null
);

$turno = 2; // 1 - Manhã | 2 - Tarde

// Define variável para armazenar funcionário
$funcId = null;


// Consulta se o cliente tem cadastro com base no CPF e pega o funcionário associado
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT funcionario_id FROM clientes WHERE cpf = :cpf"); 
// Executa a query
$stmt->execute( Array(':cpf' => $novoCliente['cpf']) ); 

// Verifica se teve resultado, se sim armazena ID do funcionário
if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0)
   $funcId = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)['funcionario_id'];


// Se não tem cadastro
if (is_null($funcId)){

   // Pega o próximo funcionario da sequencia com base no turno
   // A query busca o funcionario que tem um ID MAIOR do que o ID que estiver
   // na tabela de turno no campo `lastfunc`, ou seja o próximo
   $sql  = "SELECT fu.id as id
            FROM funcionarios as fu
               INNER JOIN turnos as tu ON tu.id = fu.turno_id
            WHERE 
               fu.id > tu.lastfunc AND
               fu.turno_id = :turno
            ORDER BY fu.id ASC LIMIT 1";
   $stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
   $stmt->execute( [':turno' => $turno] ); // Executa a query

   // Se teve resultado armazena o ID do funcionário
   if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0)
      $funcId = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)['id'];
}

// Se a regra anterior não teve resultado é porque
// chegou no último da fila e não tem próximo
// ou porque não tem nenhum id no campo `lastfunc` da tabela `turno`
// Então executa a regra seguinte
if (is_null($funcId)){

   // Seleciona o primeiro funcionario
   $sql  = "SELECT id FROM funcionarios ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1";
   $stmt = $con->prepare($sql); 
   $stmt->execute(); // Executa a query

   // Se teve resultado armazena o ID do funcionário
   if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0)
      $funcId = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)['id'];

  // Se não houver funcionar é porque não existe funcionário cadastrado
}

if (is_null($funcId)){
   // Se não pegou nenhum funcionário interrompe a execução do código
   exit('Erro: Nenhum funcionário pode ser associado ao cliente. Cadastro interrompido.');
} else {
   // Se encontrou algum funcionário atualiza os dados do cliente
   $novoCliente['funcionario_id'] = $funcId;
}

// Insere o funcionário no banco com os dados
$stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO clientes (cpf, nome, funcionario_id) VALUES (:cpf, :nome, :funcionario)"); 
// Executa a query
$res = $stmt->execute( 
   Array(
      ':cpf' => $novoCliente['cpf'],
      ':nome' => $novoCliente['nome'],
      ':funcionario' => $novoCliente['funcionario_id']
   ) 
); 


if ($res){
   // Essa parte é muito IMPORTANTE
   // Tens que armazenar o ID do funcionário utilizado no turno dele,
   // para que a fila ande, pois é com base nesse campo que verificamos a 
   // posição da fila e então pegamos o próximo.
   $stmt = $con->prepare("UPDATE turnos SET lastfunc = :lfunc WHERE id = :turno"); 
   $res = $stmt->execute( 
      Array(
         ':lfunc' => $funcId,
         ':turno' => $turno
      ) 
   );
}


echo $res ? 'Sucesso' : 'Erro';
```

#### Resultado

[image: Resultado de testes]

**Obs.:** O primeiro registro saiu sem id de funcionário porque eu esqueci de atualizar a variável `$novoCliente['funcionario_id']` antes do `INSERT` do cliente.

Comment: Boa tarde KaduAmaral , muito obrigado pela resposta , nao sabia como poderia fazer. Quanto ao código , se possivel , poderia comenta-lo ? Pelo menos a parte MySql , por que nao entendo muito ainda. Do mais, saindo do serviço ja testo o código. Grato

Comment: Opa @HenriqueFelix, eu to no trampo agora também, assim que chegar em casa eu tiro um tempo pra detalhar mais a resposta. ;)

Comment: Comentado @HenriqueFelix

Comment: Boa tarde @KaduAmaral , deu certinho,muito obrigado !